# How to do a delay of timer start properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, timer, delay

Using Winforms, I need to delay execution of event `timer1_Tick` itself or may delay `timer1.Start()` as well.

I have no idea how to do that properly. Could someone give an advice?

Answer (score 1):

Just put Thread.Sleep before handle event

```
public void Timer1_tick(...){
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

or if you need to delay timer1.Start() execution

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
timer1.Start();
```

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Use another timer ("helper") that starts the intended timer at its first tick, then stop this helper timer.
2.) Cout the ticks of your timer and only execute the event handler code after the tick count exceeded a limit:

This example starts the event handler code only after the first 100 ticks:

```
int tickCount;
public void Timer1_tick(...)
{
   if( tickCount++ < 100 ) return;

   // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Two useful advices for a  such short time! That's pretty promptly! Just a thought came. And besides it would be nice to change an engine to the another one that is with more friendly and understandable UI.

Comment: Welcome to SO!
If you find my advice useful, then upvote it with the up arrow icon, this earns me credits :-)
To insert sample code, use the {} icon in the editor's toolbar.
However, uploading entire source files is not useful when asking questions.